# Snowflake: Is there a query that will return data type as I set it when creating Table? int to int, not int to number?

Tags: c#, sql, types, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

e.g.

```
create table dbdt (
  ID int,
  Name varchar(255));
```

when I query:

```
  select * from dbName.information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'schemaName' and table_name = 'dbdt'
```

results:

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| ID | NUMBER |
| NAME | TEXT |

What do I need to change in query in order to return `INT` and `VARCHAR(255)` as I set it when creating table?

Comment: but there is no `INT` just `NUMBER`, and VARCHAR(255) is also equally meaning less. And if you have some tool that needs to think there is meaning, use something like REGEX to string swap for you.

Comment: May I know what is the reason behind your request? Any use case? This might help to find an alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, you can't get those values as they get normalized for future operations, including `get_ddl`.

One option would be to go to the query history to find and parse the create statement:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html (1 year)
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html (7 days)

---

I tried to reproduce the question , and the results come empty because the underlying name of the table is in ALL-CAPS:

```sql
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'DBDT'
```

The data types have been normalized too:

```sql
select column_name, ordinal_position, data_type, character_maximum_length, numeric_precision
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'DBDT
```

[image]

`get_schema` is more permissive with the caps, but it still normalizes the types:

```sql
select get_ddl('table', 'dbdt')
```

[image]